# insert data into mysql database with PDO connection and insert with oop

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

i try to insert data into mysql database.
i created PDO connection with mysql and now i want to insert data into database with oop.
i tried a million ways but without result.

could anyone please help me?

```js
include "DB.php";

class DataOperation extends Dbh {
  public
  function insert_record($table, $fields) {
    $insert = "";
    $insert. = "INSERT INTO ".$table;
    $insert. = " (".implode(",", array_keys($fields)).
    ") VALUES ";
    $insert. = "('".implode("','", array_values($fields)).
    "')";
    $this - > pdo - > prepare($insert);
  }
}



$obj = new DataOperation;
if (isset($_POST["create"])) {
  $myArray = array(
    "firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],
    "lastname" => $_POST['lastname'],
    "email" => $_POST['email']
  );

  $obj - > insert_record("Users", $myArray);
}
```

```html
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="inputs" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <button type="submit" name="create">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

[Image of DB.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNqLt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're preparing the statement, but you should be executing it instead.

However, your code is subject to SQL injection, you should placeholders in the query.

```
public function insert_record($table,$fields){
    $field_names = array_keys($fields);
    $placeholders = array_map(function($field) { return ":$field"; }, $field_names );
    $insert = "";                     
    $insert .= "INSERT INTO " . $table;
    $insert .= " (" . implode(",", $field_names) . ") VALUES ";
    $insert .= "('" . implode(",", $placholders) . ")";
    $stmt = $this->pdo-> prepare($insert);
    $stmt->execute($fields);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi this is my working code. Try this it should work 100%

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users(firstName,password,email,lastName,image)VALUES(:firstName,:password,:email,:lastName,:image)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->bindParam("firstName", $firstName,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$password=hash('sha256',$password);
$stmt->bindParam("password", $password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam("email", $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam("lastName", $lastName,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam("image",$imgfile,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```